# Statement of Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

My textbook (Thomson, Bruckner and Bruckner) says:

> **Theorem 2.40 (Bolzano-Weierstrass)** *Every bounded sequence contains a convergent subsequence.*

Since this is from the 2nd chapter, I'm assuming the textbook is referring to sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Since $(\mathbb{R},\ d)$ is compact, *every* sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ has a subsequence that converges to a point in $\mathbb{R}$. Doesn't this mean the theorem stated in my textbook is unnecessarily weak?

Comment: I'm guessing that your $\;d\;$ is the usual, Euclidean, metric...**who told you that** $\;\Bbb R\;$ **is compact**? It is not,

Comment: Please give me an example of a subsequence of $1,2,3,\ldots$ that converges to a point in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: There seems to be some misunderstanding of the idea "compactness". The formal definition using open covers is a bit abstract and might be what you were introduced to first. To gather some intuition on the idea here are some notes on the subject: http://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Etao/preprints/compactness.pdf

Comment: Maybe you've misinterpreted that every closed and bounded subset of $R$ is compact ?

Comment: Oops, my bad; thanks, guys. But I guess $\varnothing$ is compact since it is closed and bounded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $(u_n)$ is bounded then

$$(\forall n\in\Bbb N)\;\; u_n\in[a,b]$$

which means that $(u_n)$ is a sequence of elements in the compact $[a,b]$ and it has a convergent subsequence.

$(\Bbb R,| \; |)$ is not compact.